# Xamarin forms visual studio for Mac clean-namespace problem

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio, .net-standard

I have created a Xamarin forms application using .net standard. Then I added a .net standard library project to the solution that will include common codes such as renders, behaviours etc. I include the reference of common .net standard library project to the main Xamarin forms project by right clicking on dependencies and Edit References menu. Finally I try to include the namespace of renderer files on the content page of main Xamarin forms by specifying the below line
using Xamarin.Forms;

```
namespace MyProject.Shared.Renderer
{
    public class ExtendedEntry : Entry
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty IsBorderErrorVisibleProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IsBorderErrorVisible), typeof(bool), typeof(ExtendedEntry),
            false, BindingMode.TwoWay);

        public bool IsBorderErrorVisible
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(IsBorderErrorVisibleProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IsBorderErrorVisibleProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly BindableProperty BorderErrorColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(BorderErrorColor), typeof(Color), typeof(ExtendedEntry),
            null, BindingMode.TwoWay);

        public Color BorderErrorColor
        {
            get { return (Color)GetValue(BorderErrorColorProperty); }
            set { SetValue(BorderErrorColorProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly BindableProperty ErrorTextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ErrorText), typeof(string), typeof(ExtendedEntry), string.Empty,
            BindingMode.TwoWay);

        public string ErrorText
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(ErrorTextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ErrorTextProperty, value); }
        }
    }
}
xmlns:controls=“clr-namespace:MyProject.Shared.Renderer:assembly:MyProject.Shared”

Then I reference the control as
<controls:ExtendedEntry />
```

But this gives build error that says ExtendedEntry is not found in the assembly MyProject.Shared

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry...I had done blunder...a real blunder.

I typed  ":" instead of "=" in assembly attribute.

It should be 
xmlns:controls=“clr-namespace:MyProject.Shared.Renderer:assembly=MyProject.Shared”

Comment: Good that you found the solution

Answer (score 0):

Well actually this issue is quite common what happens is your project is not compiled properly or after compiling the bin and obj are missing this class which is fine.

Solution:

- Delete all bin obj folders from all the projects in your solution.
- Now individually build all your projects based on dependency i.e. if you have four projects A, B, iOS and Android and B is dependent on A i.e. it has a reference to A then you will first clean build A then B and then any amongst iOS and Android.
- If even after this your issue is not resolved then you might want to restart VS all together

In case you still face this issue feel free to revert.

Good luck

Comment: I let you know once I implement your solution. Thank you very much

Comment: Sure no problem

Comment: Can you add the whole page code for extended entry?

Comment: code added please. I am using Visual Studio for MAC not vs2017

Comment: @TishaAnand I know you are using Visual studio for mac!